# How to add l5-repository in laravel-livewire project?

Tags: laravel, repository, laravel-livewire

In  laravel-livewire / project I have a need to use Repositories.
I found library https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository
and loooking at sample how to assign Repository to PostsController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\PostRepository;

class PostsController extends BaseController {

    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(PostRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    ....
}
```

I try to make similar with component :

```
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\FacilityRepositoryInterface;


class Facilities extends Component
{ 
    use WithPagination;

    public $form= [
        'name'=>'',
        'descr'=> '',
        'created_at'=> '',
        'is_reopen'       => false,
    ];

    public $current_facility_id;
    public $filter_name= '';
    public $updateMode = 'browse';

    protected $FacilityRepository;

    public function __construct(FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository)
    {
        $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $backend_per_page = Settings::getValue('backend_per_page', CheckValueType::cvtInteger, 20);

        $this->emit('facility_opened', [ 'mode'=>'browse', 'id'=>null ] );

        return view('livewire.admin.facilities.container', [
            'facilityDataRows' => $this->FacilityRepository->filterWithPagination(
                 [
                     'name'=>$this->filter_name,
                     'per_page'=> $backend_per_page
                 ]
            ),
            'facility_rows_count'=> $this->facility_rows_count
        ]);
    }
```

where filterWithPagination is method of

```
class FacilityRepository extends BaseRepository implements FacilityRepositoryInterface
{
    private $UserRepository;
    ...
    
I found definition of __construct in in vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Component.php as :
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        $this->ensureIdPropertyIsntOverridden();

        $this->initializeTraits();
    }
```

Is there is a valid way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same concerns. I think livewire does not currently support dependency injection. What you can do right now is inject your repository into the mount method.

```
  public function mount(FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository)
    {
        $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the `mount` method for dependency injection

So this should work

```php
class Facilities extends Component {
  public function mount(FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository) {
    $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
  }
}
```

See docs: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/rendering-components#injecting-parameters

Answer (score 0):

If your action requires any services that should be resolved via Laravel's dependency injection container, you can list them in the action's signature before any additional parameters

```
public function addTodo(TodoService $todoService, $id, $name)
    {
        ...
    }
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions

Answer (score 0):

use this in your livewire component

```php
 public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->setRepository();
    }

    public function setRepository()
    {
        $this->cityRepository = App::make(CityRepository::class);
        $this->districtRepository = App::make(DistrictRepository::class);
        $this->villageRepository = App::make(VillageRepository::class);
    }
```